# What's a Scala 'killer app'?

Tags: scala

I'm a Java dev thinking about investing time in learning Scala to develop future apps. I've read quite a bit about the advantages of Scala over Java, but they're a bit abstract to really sell it to me emotionally.

Can someone suggest an example of an application that would really suit being developed with Scala, as opposed to Java?

Comment: @Dario: Twitter is not written in Java, is it? I think they are using Ruby on Rails.

Comment: @elusive - the twitter front-end is RoR, the message queue back-end is based on Scala

Comment: Scala is a general-purpose language. There's no specific "killer app" it's designed for. But its "abstract advatages" make writing any application easier than the corresponding program in Java.

Answer (score 8):

I think, the companies listed at [**Scala in the Enterprise**](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/1658) on scala-lang.org are the examples that the community can be proud of. They use Scala for building high-concurrency (and heavy-load) distributed scalabale applications with expressive type-safe lightweight APIs, great abilities for code-reuse and creating internal DSLs, development productivity and for many more reasons.

Just to give some names:

- [lift-based](http://liftweb.com/) [**foursquare**](http://foursquare.com/) and [**Novel Pulse**](http://www.novell.com/products/pulse/).
- **twitter**
- linked.in's [**Signal**](http://www.infoq.com/articles/linkedin-scala-jruby-voldemort) and [**Norbert**](http://days2010.scala-lang.org/node/138/159)
- CapitalIQ [**ClariFI**](http://clarifi.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Anything that's massively parallelized that uses the Actors idiom from Erlang would be a 'killer' in my view.

Comment: But the actors library "Akka" has bindings for Java actors too. And, implicit in your answer, it doesn't differentiate scala from Erlang!

Comment: True - it'd be equally killer in Erlang.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is "all of them". Scala is strictly a superset of Java, so you gain expressive power and time savings, and you lose nothing except Java's limitations.

Answer (score 2):

[many...](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/1658)

Answer (score 0):

This is *such* a daft question. Scala is a turing complete language: ergo it is equivalent in what can be developed to any other TC language.

It has access to all JVM libraries (including those written in Java) and hence has a *leg up* in terms of access to databases, media APIs, networking *et cetera et cetera et cetera*. Being a JVM language, it has the advantage of write-once-run-anywhere (WORA).

But of course Java has these as well! So what is Scala's strength? Well, clarity, expressivity, maintainability, extensibility *et cetera et cetera et cetera*.

And what app does this point you to as being a killer? Well, **all of them** of course! Have some fibs!

```
def fibs = (0, 1).repeat[Stream].map { case (a, b) => b -> (a+b) } map(_._1)
```

or:

```
lazy val fibs: Stream[Int] = 0 ::# 
  ( 1 ::# 
    fib.zip(fibs.tail).map { case (a,b) => a + b)))
```

*PS. The only thing it is not very good for, is extremely close-to-the-metal, low-latency programming. And it's making inroads into this area too!*

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but I don't like the idea that *if it's turing complete it can be used for everything*. It's like saying you can write interrupt handlers in Javascript.

Comment: Yes, but then I went on to point out that it also had the same set of libraries written for it as Java. Scala can have a killer feature, for sure - but the question, as currently posed, just *makes no sense*

Comment: "it's making inroads into this area too!" << How so?

Comment: Well, i was referring to what Kunle Olukotun talked about at ScalaDays2010 - http://days2010.scala-lang.org/node/136. It was the keynote speech on the second day and I expect we'll start seeing the "fruits" of this work over the next 6-12 months. It was about using Scala to create a DSL which compiles down to a parallel execution platform. At least, that's what I think he was saying!

Comment: VI (the editor) is Turing complete. That doesn't mean I would like to use it for my day to day programming needs. Scala make some things easier than java. I think that's what the question was.

Comment: But Matthieu, my point still stands. To paraphrase the question; *this vi is awesome, what's a killer document I can write with it?*